# Bf-f8hp radios and no idea what I'm doing

Tags: legal, ht, baofeng

My brother just bought me and himself a set of bf-f8hp radios for setting up two way communication while we are on long motorcycle trips. Now, this radio seems like overkill and I don't want to meet with anything illegal. How can I set this up?

Secondary question, what other cool stuff can I do with it?

Completely oblivious when it comes to this stuff, but I'm eager to learn.

Comment: This seems far too broad. How can you set it up? Well I suppose it would depend on what you intend to do with it, but as you are asking about that as well, the scope of the question is rather ill-defined.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Yes, it's broad, and maybe OT, but let's leave it open (at least for now) to address his admirable question about the legality. And getting a ham license is "other cool stuff". :-)

Comment: @MikeWaters Well, the question doesn't specify a jurisdiction, and we have a close reason for that, too.

Comment: Mike, @PhilFrost-W8II has a good point. People from *many* countries are active here. **What country do you live in?**

Comment: @MikeWaters I live in the US. I'm looking to use it for two way communication on motorcycle rides primarily. Now that I'm researching I might be interested in making it more of a hobby.

I saw something called MURS which might be what I need?

Comment: Get a ham licence, or get a specific MURS radio.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell, the BF-F8HP is very similar to the UV-5R. These links may help answer your question.

- [licensing a group of BaoFeng BF-888S](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/licensing-a-group-of-baofeng-bf-888s)
- [Can a Baofeng UV-5R+ be used on FRS, GMRS, and MURS?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/can-a-baofeng-uv-5r-be-used-on-frs-gmrs-and-murs)
- [On which of these frequencies can I transmit without a license?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/on-which-of-these-frequencies-can-i-transmit-without-a-license)
- [Using my Baofeng UV-5R to talk to walkie talkies](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/623/using-my-baofeng-uv-5r-to-talk-to-walkie-talkies)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify in which country you will be using the radios, and that affects the answer greatly.  The world is a big place, and the Internet gets to most of it!

In most countries, however, the only way to use such a radio legally will be to get a commercial VHF or UHF license, or an amateur radio (ham radio) license.  A ham radio license that lets you use such radios is pretty easy to get in quite a lot of countries, and often inexpensive.  (In Canada, for example, it's possible to get a callsign for free or low cost, not counting whatever study materials you choose to get.)

Answer (score 2):

These are great little radios. I really do like them. However, in the U.S., there seems to be no way to legally transmit with these radios without a license. Not even on the unlicensed bands since these radios are not certified for FRS.

My suggestion is to get a Ham Radio license. You only need a technician license for VHF and UHF and wouldn't require more than a day or two to study and pass the test. Good luck.

Comment: I was considering this for my needs. www.buytwowayradios.com/blog/2008/09/murs_unlicensed_vhf.aspx